# How to write a tensorflowjs-dependent library that will import from either tfjs or tfjs-node appropriately

Tags: node.js, webpack, tensorflow.js, javascript-import, tensorflowjs

I am writing a TypeScript library that is basically a clone of the python tensorflow-probability package. I am intending to use this library in other projects, both server-side and in the browser. When the downstream project imports the tfjs-probability code, I would like the tfjs backend to utilize whatever resources are available in the runtime of the user.

Is there a canonical way to write the library code so that it imports `tensor` from '@tensorflow/tfjs' when the package should be used on the front-end, but imports from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node', when used in a node environment?

Should I be configuring this in my build tool (webpack)?

for example. In my tfjs-probability package I have:

```js
import { tensor } from '@tensorflow/tfjs'; // alternately '@tensorflow/tfjs-node'
export class NormalDist { //code that uses tensors }
```

and I am imagining that I would do something like this in a downstream project:

```js
import { NormalDist } from 'tfjs-probability';
const n = new NormalDist()
```

and somehow my library would be smart enough to know whether to use tensorflowjs webgl (in the browser) or tensorflowjs-node.

Comment: If you're in a node.js environment, just use `require()`.  It supports the CommonJS exportation out of a UMD module.  If you use `import {} from whatev.js` you'll have to either transpile or deal with the `.mjs` extension.

Comment: Hi zero298, thanks for the suggestion. To clarify, both the source library (tfjs-probability) and the projects where I plan to use the library (angular app and nestJS-like server), are written in typescript and will be bundled with webpack. I'm hoping that I can just write `import { something } from tfjs-probability` in both, and that the tfjs-probability package will somehow be smart enough to use either '@tensorflow/tfjs' or '@tensorflow/tfjs-node'.